# How to detect device back button event in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

We are developing an application in which we want to exit a login screen of press event of a device (hardware) back button.
  So can you please help me on that and tell me how I can  exit login screen on back button press event of device?
  If we want to exit App(application) then what should we do to exit App(application) on back press event of device.
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void beforeSearchForm(Form f) {
    Command cancel = new Command(" "){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Log.p("Cancel/back pressed from beforeSearchForm() (yes its Keypad.!!)");        
             if(Dialog.show("Logout ?", "Do you want to log out ?", Dialog.TYPE_INFO, null, "Yes", "No")){
            //its Yes
             }else{
            //its No
             }    
            }
    };
    f.setBackCommand(cancel);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a command in codename one for this and you can apply it in your Form.

```
Maybe : myForm.setBackCommand(new Command(){...});
```

You can manage back button pressed behavior with this.
Don't forget to take a look a developer guide , it's a huge help when you have these kind of questions.

Comment: hey thanks . but i want to exit my application on device back button press with showing dialog "do you want to exit".

Comment: So you have to set the Command (defined in setBackCommand) behavior to print a yes/no dialog

Comment: Tim's answer is correct, you should elaborate what's not working for you. Notice you can override the `actionPerformed` method in the command to get custom functionality.